# Function that gives a certain star histogram

Tags: python

How can I modify this code I have written

```
def star_histogram(l):
    for i in l:
        output = ''
        times = i
        while( times > 0 ):
            output += '*'
            times = times - 1
        print(output)
```

which when I run this assert

```
assert star_histogram([3, 5, 4])
```

gives this

```
***
*****
****
```

to instead give me this

```
assert star_histogram([3, 5, 4]) == "***\n*****\n****"
```

Note that I don't want to change the assert, only my code

Comment: To clarify, do you want the function to return "***\n*****\n****" depending on the input?

Comment: Your `star_histogram` does not return anything atm. If you want the assert to work, instead of printing you should return a string right? (which can later be printed if needed)

Comment: Yes, as you can see in the case  [3, 5, 4] the number determines how many *'s which are then followed by \n

Comment: Also, notice that in Python you can write `"*" * i` so there’s no need for your loop. In fact, your code can be summarized into a single [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): `["*" * i for i in l]`

Comment: @urban the assert gives me the **** lines I showed right now. But any help that makes the output of the assert look like I want it to are welcome. And I am a beginner at Python so showing me what you mean help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
def star_histogram(l):
    value = ""
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if i != 0:
            value += "\n" + "*" * l[i]
        else:
            value = "*" * l[i]
    return value
```

Which will return the output with `len(l)-1` number of newlines and the correct number of stars.

For reference, here's another way of going about it, using python's `join()` function:

```
def star_histogram(l):
    list = ["*" * i for i in l]
    value = "\n".join(list)
    return value
```

Comment: It doesn't output anything when I run the assert :/

Comment: assert statements can only take in a boolean condition, true or false. If you want to print the output and then use assert, you can place `print(value)` before `return value`, then after the function returns, use this: `assert star_histogram([3, 5, 4]) == "***\n*****\n****"`

Answer (score 0):

No need to use while, you can use: '*' * i

```
def star_histogram(l):
    for i in l:
        output = ''
        output ='*' * i
        print(output)

star_histogram([3, 5, 4])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code can be summarized into a single [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

```
>>> l = [3, 5, 6]
>>> ["*" * i for i in l] 
['***', '*****', '****']
```